# which word equals to this phrase: to keep away from sth one hates it

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary, concept

I am looking up a formal word with this definition:' to keep away from something which one hates it.'

Comment: "avoid" seems obvious.  Do you mean a word like "avoid" but with a stronger sense of urgency or importance?  What about "shun"?

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence into which the word will be used? It'll help give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a single word that contains a connotation as strong as hating something, but there's one with a sense of avoiding because of dislike, from Collins

> [Eschew](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eschew)
>
> (transitive) to keep clear of or abstain from (something disliked,
>   injurious, etc); shun; avoid

If you don't mind an expression, the strongest common one I know is

> [to avoid someone or something like the plague](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-avoid-someone-or-something-like-the-plague)

same source.